# couchbase server is not responding. The GUI shows that the views are being indexed

Tags: couchbase

The Couchbase server is not working. The GUI shows that the views are being indexed and the server doesn't respond. I am also getting a warning :

> Fail Over Warning: At least two servers are required to provide
>   replication.

I have tried restarting the server and also tried to disable the replication but hasn't worked for me.

Kindly help.

Comment: This question does not contain nearly enough information to start troubleshooting your issue. You state the error you see, but nothing describing your cluster, what has happened that might cause this recently, version numbers, what state does the GUI say the nodes are in, and lots of other things. I am sure there are people here, including myself, that are capable of helping you, but you need to provide a lot more information to have that happen.

Comment: I got the issue corrected, this issue was due to the low diskspace.

Answer (score 1):

The Fail Over warning is because you are only running a server. It is nothing to be concerned about providing you're aware of the risks of running a single node and foregoing the benefits of running a distributed system across multiple servers/nodes.

As for an unresponsive cluster, it may be any number of things, but without knowing more about your case (e.g. the specifications of the hardware running the software - recommendations for which can be found on [Couchbase's website](http://blog.couchbase.com/how-many-nodes-part-3-hardware-considerations)), any speculation would be fairly baseless.

Comment: I am using couchbase  Version: 3.0.1 Community Edition . Please find the screen print to know the cluster details http://chromosis.com/public_sharing/couchbase_cluster_overview.png. I have no clue why this issue has occurred. The views are being index is what the interface says but its hung since days and when I query no records are fetched and it gets hung.

Comment: Below are the details of the exception : An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: CouchbaseException

Message: Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network
conditions or increase the timeout

Comment: How many cores does each node have? Looking at the number of views you have, you'd need between 6-8 CPU cores per server node, with the exact number dependent on other factors. Timeouts and unresponsiveness combined with the number of views you have suggests and under provisioned cluster. See [this blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/how-many-nodes-part-3-hardware-considerations) for more details on sizing recommendations.